# SiriKit - INSendPaymentIntentHandling - Sharing custom classes in IntentHandler which were written in the app breaks functionality

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sirikit

I'm trying to integrate Siri to my app with **INSendPaymentIntentHandling**. I've made all necessary changes required (info.plist, certificates, extensions, etc).

Everything works in perfect sync, and a Siri dialog appears to confirm payment when I say - "Send money using xxxxxx".

But when I use one of classes written for my app (ContactsManager), Siri goes like - "You need to continue in the app" with no dialogue which was shown earlier, and message on console appears as - "Program ended with exit code: 0"

I already did the necessary steps to share a class between targets by checking Siri target from right pane in Xcode.

Kindly suggest mistakes.

Comment: Hi! I have the same problem. Did you find how to fix it?